# Is it possible to trim text in a textarea from the popup panel?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon

I am trying to make an extension that will allow the user to trim text.

Example:
`" 1234 "`

to `"1234"`

If they click on the addon icon the popup will displays a textarea where they can enter text. Something like [this](https://gyazo.com/b1fe855ad4223f06442588839a35484b).

Once the trim button is clicked, the trimmed text will be displayed in the textarea

However right now it's not returning anything when the button is clicked.

JS

```
function myFunc() {
    var result = document.getElementById("text-area").value;
    result = result.trim();
    document.getElementById("text-area").value = result
}
```

HTML

```
        <form id="form1">
        <textarea id="text-area" rows="20" cols="50" placeholder="text here..."></textarea><br>
                <button class="button" onclick="myFunc()">Trim</button>
        </form>
```

**Things I have tried**

- use `.textContent` instead of `.value` to get the text from the textarea.
- looked into [storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage) options, at the time it seemed a bit excessive for such a simple task.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `innerText`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

> innerText is easily confused with Node.textContent, but there are
>   important differences between the two. Basically, innerText is aware
>   of the rendered appearance of text, while textContent is not.